# How can I cast spells without target an enemy?

Tags: diablo-iii

Using elective mode, I am trying to use spells other than the signature spells (wizard) for left click.

Few spells (except Archon Orb) seems to work well .  For instance, I set it to Archon and it never fires. I have tried targeting a mob when I left click and that does not fire it.

Is there a way to cast Archon Orb (for example), without the need of a target?

Comment: You can not add certain abilities to the left click because they make no sense as target-only abilities. Left-click actions have to have a target. Archon does not need a target. This is just "how it was designed" and says so right on the tooltip for the greyed out abilities.

Comment: @Resorath Archon is not one of those abilities. Shift + click allows it to work without a target.

Comment: I edited your question to fit what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, what you want is `Shift + Click`. If you bind an ability to left-click, you can hold the shift key to force the game to use that ability instead of moving, etc.

I do not know if this works for Archon and other Wizard abilities, but it works well for Demon Hunters, for example if you want to attack an enemy off-screen, you can shift-left-click to attack instead of moving where you clicked the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Secondary attack is right click - Archon works fine on right click. I am unsure why it doesn't behave as expected when using left click.

I've just tested this in game with my wizard, if you bound the Archon ability to your primary attack:

- your Primary attack button (left click) and then hold shift and click on the ground it will activate Archon form.
- clicking on an enemy with Archon bound to your Primary attack button will not trigger Archon form.

However, for additional testing, I put Mirror Images/Slow Time on my Primary attack button. Upon clicking the ground I moved as I expected, but upon clicking an enemy the ability was used.

From my testing it just appears to be some weird behaviour with Archon, there may be some built in fail safe to stop you from triggering long cool downs (Archon is our only long cool down) when trying to move maybe?

Comment: Thanks, I would vote it up but I do not have enough reputation to do that yet.  LOL